# Make a div track down when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I want to have the ability to move the `.secDiv` down when resizing the browser. Currently the coloured squares in the `.boxes` overlap the `.secDiv` when scaling the browser down.

Please assist.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.boxes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.red {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.green {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.blue {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.secDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.red2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.green2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.blue2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="boxes">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="secDiv">
        <div class="red2"></div>
        <div class="green2"></div>
        <div class="blue2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using dynamic heights such as `%` or `vh`. Because you have a fixed height of 300px. It will try to keep that height when resizing, and simply your content doesn't fit in a 300px height when you resize. You can use something simple like `overflow-y: scroll` if you want to use a fixed height, but I don't think that is what you're going for. I added `width: 50%` on your `boxes` and `secDiv` classes. You can use either `50%`, `25%` or whatever you desire for your end result. But I would stay away from using fixed units when looking for a responsive design.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.boxes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.red {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.green {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.blue {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.secDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.red2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.green2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.blue2 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="secDiv">
        <div class="red2"></div>
        <div class="green2"></div>
        <div class="blue2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added the `@media` query, so it changes responsively when the browser resizes, and the `<div>`'s break nicely under each other.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
      height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .boxes {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .red {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  .green {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  .blue {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  
  .secDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .red2 {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  .green2 {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  .blue2 {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
  }

  @media(max-width: 994px) {
      .secDiv, .boxes {
          height: 600px;
      }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="secDiv">
        <div class="red2"></div>
        <div class="green2"></div>
        <div class="blue2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```